# CMake FIND_PACKAGE succeeds but returns wrong path

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to have CMake 2.8.6 link to boost::program_options using the following code in my CMakeLists.txt

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

ADD_EXECUTABLE (segment segment.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (segment ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The find command seems to succeed but passes the wrong directory to the linker. The package is actually in:

```
`/usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.5`
```

but `CMakeFiles/segment.dir/link.txt` lists the following:

```
/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.4.6/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/segment.dir/segment.cpp.o  -o segment -rdynamic /usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.5 -lpthread -lrt -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/lib64
```

Note the extra `lib64` in the path. Also, the -l flag in front of the path seems to be missing.

When running CMake it reports that it correctly finds the package, and the `{$Boost_LIBRARIES}` variable seems to list the correct libs:

```
Boost  found.
Found Boost components:
   program_options
${Boost_LIBRARIES} - optimized;boost_program_options-mt-shared;debug;boost_program_options-mt-shared-debug
```

The generated CMakeCache.txt file starts with:

```
//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Boost.
Boost_DIR:PATH=/usr/lib64/boost

//Boost include directory
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR:FILEPATH=/usr/include
```

Which seems to be correct. But when running make it uses the path in link.txt above and I get the error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.5', needed by `segment'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/segment.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What might cause this extra injection of a subdir into the path? What might cause link.txt to be generated in this way? And how do I fix it (or work around it)?

Comment: Can you add `SET(Boost_DEBUG 1)` before `FIND_PACKAGE` and `MESSAGE("\${Boost_LIBRARIES} - ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")` after `FIND_PACKAGE` in your CMakeLists.txt.  Then delete your CMakeCache.txt, run CMake and paste the output as an edit to your question.

Comment: @Fraser It seems to find the correct libs, here is the output (also included above): `${Boost_LIBRARIES} - optimized;boost_program_options-mt-shared;debug;boost_program_options-mt-shared-debug`

Comment: As a workaround, how do I set the link path manually?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This problem occurs when using some older versions of boost with `cmake-2.8.6-rc2` or later, where the boost package finding code was changed.

The problem can be worked around by specifying `-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=ON` on the cmake command line.

The actual commit where this problem is introduced is 7da796d1fdd7cca07df733d010cd343f6f8787a9, and can be [viewed here](http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commit;h=7da796d1fdd7cca07df733d010cd343f6f8787a9).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with the boost-devel distributed file: /usr/lib64/boost/Boost-relwithdebinfo.cmake

The cmake-2.6 package does not use this file at all, because the FindBoost.cmake file returns (correct) full-paths to boost libraries. The cmake28-2.8.8 FindBoost.cmake file returns library strings like "boost_date_time-mt-shared", which are targets defined in /usr/lib64/boost/Boost-relwithdebinfo.cmake.

At the very top of /usr/lib64/boost/Boost-relwithdebinfo.cmake, a variable named _IMPORT_PREFIX is defined from the location of the cmake file itself, and then used like so:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "RelWithDebInfo".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
SET(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)

# Import target "boost_date_time-static" for configuration "RelWithDebInfo"
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET boost_date_time-static APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELWITHDEBINFO)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(boost_date_time-static PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib64/libboost_date_time.a"
  )
```

This sets _IMPORT_PREFIX to "/usr/lib64", which is concatenated with another string that has /lib64/ in it as well. I found that if I simply change the file to include a 3rd GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT call, it works fine. Like so:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "RelWithDebInfo".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
SET(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)

# Import target "boost_date_time-static" for configuration "RelWithDebInfo"
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET boost_date_time-static APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELWITHDEBINFO)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(boost_date_time-static PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib64/libboost_date_time.a"
  )
```

Comment: What is this all about cmake being better than most autohell? I've wasted weeks pulling my hair out until I've read this.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an issue with CMake 2.8.6 on CentOS. When doing the same with 2.6.4 or 2.8.3 it works correctly. Also with 2.8.7 on OS X it also works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I also see the problem on the pre-compiled cmake version 2.8.8 using CentOS 64-bit 6.2

Comment: And backing down to 2.8.3 fixed it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue on cmake version 2.8.11.2 with boost-1.41.0-18.el6.x86_64

The approved answer does not seem satisfactory because appending this define to the cmake runtime I get:

CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

```
Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE
```

I can't seem to comment or downvote due to not participating in stackoverflow enough. That is a chicken and egg problem!

I also can't seem to upvote the explanation by Kai Meyer. However, I think this really explains the problem.

From what I am gathering it seems that in summary, FindBoost.cmake provided by CMake seems to all of a sudden fail to find Boost, so the find code is now searching via the boost provided script for cmake, which in turn has a bug and seems to not return the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

while building package from AUR following prefix helped to find **Boost**:

```
BOOST_ROOT=/usr
```

example:

```
BOOST_ROOT=/usr makepkg -si
```