# Got "/usr/lib64/lib64" while using cmake with boost

Tags: boost, cmake

I have a cmake controlled package that use FindBoost.cmake to locate boost. Two of my users reported this bug to me, but I cannot reproduce it on my computer.

While solving dependencies of a target executable, the make claims following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5', needed by `src/ht-asm'.  Stop.
```

I have set the library dirs in my makefile, before adding the target "ht-asm":

```
link_directories(
    ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)
```

And I have totally no idea on this issue, as I never met them on my computers (one with Debian 6 and the other with Fedora 18).

Comment: @ruslo Yes, I have set target_link_libraries for each of my targets.

Comment: @ruslo This issue happened two times. At the very beginning, I did not use `link_directories`, and such issue was reported by a user. After that, someone told me to add `link_directories`, and this issue was reported again.

Comment: `someone told me to add link_directories` IMHO bad advice (:

Comment: This file does not exist. I guess it should be `/usr/lib64/libboost_XXX.so`, but cmake assigned this filename as a dependency to my target.

Comment: @ruslo find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    filesystem
    program_options
    regex
    system
    thread
)

Comment: I've yet to understand the need for any other build utility than make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here which worked for cmake 2.8.12.1 with boost 1.41.0-18

- [CMake FIND_PACKAGE succeeds but returns wrong path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948375/cmake-find-package-succeeds-but-returns-wrong-path)

Here is the verbatim text ...

---

The problem is with the boost-devel distributed file: `/usr/lib64/boost/Boost-relwithdebinfo.cmake`

The `cmake-2.6` package does not use this file at all, because the `FindBoost.cmake` file returns (correct) full paths to boost libraries. The `cmake28-2.8.8 FindBoost.cmake` file returns library strings like `boost_date_time-mt-shared`, which are targets defined in `/usr/lib64/boost/Boost-relwithdebinfo.cmake`.

At the very top of `/usr/lib64/boost/Boost-relwithdebinfo.cmake`, a variable named `_IMPORT_PREFIX` is defined from the location of the cmake file itself, and then used like so:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "RelWithDebInfo".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
SET(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)

# Import target "boost_date_time-static" for configuration "RelWithDebInfo"
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET boost_date_time-static APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELWITHDEBINFO)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(boost_date_time-static PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib64/libboost_date_time.a"
  )
```

This sets `_IMPORT_PREFIX` to `/usr/lib64`, which is concatenated with another string that has `/lib64/` in it as well. I found that if I simply change the file to include a 3rd `GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT` call, it works fine. Like so:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "RelWithDebInfo".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
SET(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)

# Import target "boost_date_time-static" for configuration "RelWithDebInfo"
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET boost_date_time-static APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELWITHDEBINFO)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(boost_date_time-static PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib64/libboost_date_time.a"
  )
```