# linking boost libaries using cmake 2.8.8

Tags: c++, boost, centos, cmake

I am struggling with cmake-baed boost linking problem that I searched on stackoverflow, and on other forums but to no avail.

I am compiling a C++ program suite (depending on different libraries, in addition to Boost) on a cluster where Boost is already installed (and I know the full path). After getting weird linking errors for boost with cmake while compiling, I thought of first compiling a very simple boost-cmake example to solve the problem.

The code is given below.

```
#include <boost/program_options/options_description.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/option.hpp>
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ;

return 0;
}
```

I am using the following CMakeLists.txt file for building.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/include) 
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/lib)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

message("Boost include dir is ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("Boost library dir is ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR}")
message("Boost libraries are at ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( main ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

When I compile using cmake, I get the following output

```
    x_ikrul@ikramu build]$  emacs ../CMakeLists.txt
Display localhost:39.0 unavailable, simulating -nw
[x_ikrul@triolith1 build]$ rm -rf *
[x_ikrul@triolith1 build]$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /software/apps/comp_wrapper/gnu/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /software/apps/comp_wrapper/gnu/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /software/apps/comp_wrapper/gnu/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /software/apps/comp_wrapper/gnu/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Boost  found.
Found Boost components:
program_options
Boost include dir is /usr/include
Boost library dir is /software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/lib
Boost libraries are at optimized;boost_program_options-mt-shared;debug;boost_program_options-mt-shared-debug
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/x_ikrul/Downloads/boost_example/build
```

THE PROBLEM comes when I "make" the code as given below.

```
    x_ikrul@ikramu build]$make 
Scanning dependencies of target main
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.5', needed by `main'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As you may see, although CMake shows the lib directory for boost to be /software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/lib, strangely at linking time, it is referring to a different non-exising directory.

Anybody came across error like this? The cluster is running CentOS release 6.5, the boost (where I am pointing) is 1.55.0 and the cmake I am using is 2.8.8.

Comment: Your boost include dir is also not being found correctly? `Boost include dir is /usr/include`

Comment: You are right. 
In fact, when I tried this example on a different cluster with same version of cmake/boost, everything goes smooth but with the current machine, it is giving these strange errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994101/757777) suggests adding `-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=ON` on the cmake command line.

It seems to be caused by the fact that some CMake versions do not work well with some Boost versions.

And I agree to what user Fraser said. These lines do not make sense

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/include) 
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/lib)
```

as those variables are used by CMake to store the result from the Boost search. Read more about it in his answer.

Comment: You are right, I have now removed the set(.) lines from CMakeLists.txt to make it more transparent. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're not setting the hint paths correctly.

From the [FindBoost module docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html):

> This module reads hints about search locations from variables:
>
> `BOOST_ROOT`             - Preferred installation prefix
>     (or BOOSTROOT)
>
> `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`       - Preferred include directory e.g. `<prefix>/include`
>
> `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`       - Preferred library directory e.g. `<prefix>/lib`
>
> `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS`  - Set to `ON` to disable searching in locations not
>                            specified by these hint variables. Default is `OFF`.
>
> ...
>
> and saves search results persistently in CMake cache entries:
>
> `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR`         - Directory containing Boost headers
>
> `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR`         - Directory containing Boost libraries

So, your lines:

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/include) 
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/lib)
```

aren't actually setting hint variables - you want to be setting `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`; possibly also `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS`.

This is best not hard-coded inside your CMakeLists.txt since that's not portable.  Rather pass these on the command line when invoking CMake:

```
cmake . -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/include -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/software/apps/boost/1.55.0/build06/lib -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON
```

You can also get a much better idea of what's going on if you set `Boost_DEBUG` to `ON`.

As an aside, you shouldn't need the `link_directories` call since the full paths to the Boost libs are passed in the `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: I tried this, and when I print the BOOST_INCLUDEDIR and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR, they are not outputting this path. I tried using BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR/BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS and BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR/BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS but couldn't make it.

I tried the code/scripts on different cluster, and there they compiled happily. Do you think there might be some clash with other loaded libraries?

Feeling grateful for your assistance :-)

Comment: These values *could* be getting set/overwritten somewhere else before control gets to the FindCMake module.  Can you maybe update your question with how you're setting these, where in the CMakeLists.txt you're printing them out, and what the output is with `cmake . -DBoost_DEBUG=ON`?

Comment: I was finally able to link the intended paths using the BOOST_ROOT, BOOST_INCLUDEDIR and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR. I was initially confused whether to use BOOST_INCLUDEDIR or BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS (input and output variables). This answer made it clear. Thanks a lot man...

Comment: Another potential source of problem, in my case, may be the presence of GCC and intel compilers (and many versions in each case) on the cluster. I think I need to keep track of the versions (under which different libraries were built) pretty stricly as well.